# Slider graphic not visible on Pluto

Tags: slider, julia, pluto

I've started experimenting with Pluto (had to give up on Jupyter notebook on this computer) and PlutoUI. Packages installed fine and I've been going through the sample notebooks on my Firefox browser. However, the slider doesn't seem to render properly (all that's visible is a grey circle, which although responsible isn't what a slider normally looks like). Is there a way to get it to render properly?

I'm using Julia 1.5.x, on a Linux Mint based OS, and working with the latest version of Firefox.

Thanks!

Comment: BTW, the slider works fine when I use Chromium (an open-source clone of the Chrome browser). Perhaps it's a firefox issue? Cheers

Comment: That sounds more like an issue to be raised directly on https://github.com/fonsp/Pluto.jl rather than a stackoverflow question, no?

Comment: Thank you @BenoitPasquier for the suggestion. If that's the case, then it's a more general issue than I thought. In any case, it's not a huge deal. Just being thorough, that's all. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The PlutoUI slider is just the default HTML5 slider, like in this example:

https://so-slider-invisible.glitch.me

If that slider is also invisible, then open an issue at Firefox.